# Android - local image in webview

Tags: android, image, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to diplay a local image in my webview :

```
 String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"file:///android_asset/large_image.png\"/></body>";
 webview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

This code doesn't display anything, instead of :

```
 webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/large_image.jpg");
```

This one works, but I need to have complex web page, not just a picture.

Any ideas ?

Comment: better you create html file and put it in the assets folder and access it from assets folder

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Load Html file in Webview and put your image in asset folder and read that image file using Html.

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="abc.gif" width="50px" alt="Hello">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Now Load that Html file in Webview

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");
```

Comment: What if image is in other folder of asset ?

Comment: Surprisingly, this also works for your app in release version too.

Comment: .jpg image is unable to load, can there is any other better solution?

Comment: @Piyush Kukadiya   you use  like this
 `    <img src='b/ip.png' alt='Dart logo' width='152' height='152'>`  or else     <img src='file:///android_asset/b/ip.png' alt='Dart logo' width='152' height='152'> both work

Answer (score 51):

You can also try

```
String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"large_image.png\"/></body>";

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",data , "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

Comment: I think this is the fastest method, especially if all you need is to display just one image. Thanks )

Comment: I am generating html files using code and needed to use local images in the asset folder. Tried other methods but they did not work. Yours works perfectly.

Answer (score 28):

One convenient way (often forgotten) is to use base64 embedded images in HTML content. This will also work on mobile Webkit browsers (IOS, Android..).

Point of using this method is that you can embed images on HTML content, instead of fighting with image links from webview to restricted filesystem.

```
  <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

  xxxxx = base64 encoded string of images bytes
```

If you want to provide (base64 embedded) image data from filesystem, you can for example:

1) In Android use ContentProvider - which will provide base64 formatted image strings.

```
<img src="content://.............."/>
```

2) Or you can preprocess HTML with JSOUP or similar DOM parser (before setting it to webview) and adjust image src with properly base64 encoded image.

Disadvantages of this method is overhead included in converting image to base64 string and of course in proding larger HTML data to webview.

Comment: Hi, Can you give an exemple with the this full line: <img src="content://.............."/>

Comment: This technique is only useful if the WebView has loadDataWithBaseURl` where the base URL is not `file://...`.

Answer (score 8):

Use this method.

```
mview.loadDataWithBaseURL(folder.getAbsolutePath(), content, "text/html", "windows-1252", "");
```

`folder.getAbsolutePath()` can be `"file:///android_asset"` or just `"/"`

Comment: what is content here ?

Comment: Content is actual html text like <html> ... </html>

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a `\` missing in your code

```
   String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\\"file:///android_asset/large_image.png\"/></body>";
```

Comment: With two "\", eclipse doesn't want to compile :s
I found a workaround :
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://w/t/f", data, mimeType, encoding, null);

Seems that loadData() is buggued ...

Answer (score 1):

The image will not load unless you have:

```
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

If you are using a html file, it should be in a folder called "assets" in /app/src/main. If you don't have that folder then make it. Then load the html file with:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

If you put the image in the same folder as the html file, then in the html file you can just do a normal:

```
<img src='myimage.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sourse, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

the best approach for me was to create my `.html` file with all the texts and images in MS word, and save the file as an `.html` file and copying both `.html` file and the corresponding attachments folder into assets folder and giving the address of .html file in asset folder to `webview.loadUrl()`...
Here is what you need to Do...

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/learning1/learning1.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zain's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764224/4221299) worked for me. I forgot to add my folder **www** having HTML files and other subfolders of css and images etc.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/www/",data , "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

..

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and straightforward way is to create a html file with a  html editor like `kompozer` or whatever you like.

Put your html file in the assets folder and call `webView.loadUrl(filename)`. The assets folder should also contain all pictures which you are referencing in your html files.

Correct in advance in the html file the path to your images in a way, that you only file down the pure filename. The file name you pass to loadUrl must be prefixed with  `file:///android_asset/`.

If the picture or file does not load, check the filenames for **blanks**, **hyphen** and other weird stuff and change the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I Know the Question is answered correctly, but I am going to implement in an effective way.

> Step-1 make an HTML file in asset folder

ex:-imageLaod.html

Note: Here In HTML file we have implemented FullScreen Image by giving  **style="width:100%"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
       <title>Load Image</title>
          <style type="text/css">
                h3{
                color:blue;
                }
        </style>   
    </head>
  <body>
        <h3>This image loaded from app asset folder.</h3>
        <img src="yourimage.png" style="width:100%" alt="companylogo"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Step-2 put your image in the asset folder. (ex:yourimage.png)

Step-3 put below code in java file.

```
    String folderPath = "file:android_asset/";
    String fileName = "loadImage.html";
    String file = folderPath + fileName;
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.loadUrl(file);
```

and it is done. you can see the **fullscreen image with zoom in-zoom out feature of WebView**.

Hope it helps.