# Load HTML data into WebView, referencing local images?

Tags: android

If I'm loading a WebView with an HTML document directly (no web server) using WebView.loadData() is there a way for that document to reference local images? If so where do I place them, and how do I reference them?

Or alternatively is there a way to easily encode and embed bitmaps into the HTML document?

I need to display local HTML documents that include images and I'd like to avoid setting up a remote server to serve the resources.

Comment: how many images ? and are you try with `AssetManager`>

Comment: I expect 1-5 images per document, with one document and WebView per activity, so not many. Tried what with AssetManager?

Comment: I use assets. In assets folder my html files, in assets/img folder - images. Reference in html : ...  <img src="img/my_image" />  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
 String html = new String();
        html = ("<html><BODY  ><table  style='margin-top:100px;'  align='center'><tr><td><img src=\""+your_image_localpath+"\" width=\""+800+"px\" height=\""+800+"px\" ></td></tr></table> </BODY></html>" );

        webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/data/data/your_package_name/",
               html,
               "text/html",
               "utf-8",
               "");
```

Comment: this seems pretty messy as it involves copying all the images out of the assets into the app storage. If at all possible I'd rather reference the images direct from the app.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `file:///android_asset/www/image.jpg` as image `src` attribute ? If you have the html document as a file, then you can just put the images into a folder next to the file in assets.

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting. Are you saying file:///android_asset allows an HTML doc to refer directly to image resources in the APK assets?

Comment: It's a guess, modifiying something in assets at runtime is not possible, but reading data from assets should be possible.

Comment: Simliar solution, but looks a bit more elegant to me  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6134462/285431): in html use `<img src="abc.gif" width="50px" alt="Hello">` and load the html file with `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoding if you don't care about the images and they are just part of the html page.

There is another thread that explain how to use the base64 encoding [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better and more clean:

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
                    html.append("<html>");
                    html.append("<head>");
                    html.append("</head>");
                    html.append("<body>");
                    html.append("<p><img style='width: 100%;' src='your_image.png' /></p>");
                    html.append("</body></html>");
                    your_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```