# How to temporarily obscure WebView with full screen image?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-resources

Displaying an (local) image inside WebView is [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134462).

But that means it must fit within whatever my standard WebView frame has (minus title bar for example).

Before loading any page or URL into WebView I could simply achieve this by doing:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

But ***after*** some page has been loaded and rendered, the above trick no longer works.

Is there a way to obscure WebView with a full screen image? (until a new HTML page or URL is loaded, of course)

**Note:** I'm *not* interested in a [webview.loadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6127696) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your own `WebViewClient` against the `WebView` and have it override the following two methods:

- [onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)
- [onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Then, when a page starts loading, toggle your image (which you overlay in e.g. an `ImageView`) to be visible. When loading the page has finished, set it back to either `invisible` or `gone`. This will work every time a page is loaded by the `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks and upvote for the creative idea. How do I toggle my image (`R.drawable.myImage`) to be visible? The only method in WebView that hints about visibility is `WebView.setVisibility(int)` and it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Oh got it. It looks like it isn't possible to make a view out of drawable without first wrapping it a layout XML.

Comment: This won't work if you have redirects...when a redirect is loaded, it calls onPageFinished :-P