# Using UniversalImageLoader with WebView

Tags: android, webview, imageview, universal-image-loader

I am using [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) in my application. It works great for `ImageView`s, but I also have `WebView` in my application. Therefore, images are downloaded twice. Once by Universal Image Loader for `ImageView`s and once by WebView. Is it possible to use the already downloaded image in `WebView`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is answer to your question but look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview) maybe it helps you.