# How To Load Text In Webview Android?

Tags: android, webview

I want show html in text,but images not load.when save text in html file in asset folder images is display.

```
String html="<html><head></head><body> <Marquee><img src="\mnt\sdcard\osVodigi\Images\apps.png"/><img src="\mnt\sdcard\osVodigi\Images\shop.png"/><img src="\mnt\sdcard\osVodigi\Images\skype.png"/><img src="\mnt\sdcard\osVodigi\Images\word.png"/></marquee>sfdfsd</body></html>";
web.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

How I Resolve Problms?
thanks

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview) can help

Comment: I can see from your code that you are not using `\"` for double quotes. This might be giving error. Use back slash before double quotes.

Comment: web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html"); this code is ok..why use text not worked?

Comment: @user1247414 try the below

Answer (score 6):

You need to get the path of image and then use the image path in html and load it in webview.

Don't use hard coded path use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Also check if sdcard is mounted

```
 if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
 {
       //dosomething
 }
```

To get the path and load image in webview

```
File f= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyFolder"); 
String filename ="image.png" 
String imagePath = "file://"+ f.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename;
String html = "<html><head></head><body><Marquee><img src=\"" + imagePath + "\">My Scroll Text</Marquee></body></html>";
wv= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Snap shot. The image and the text does scroll

[image]

Comment: this code not Worked!

Comment: it works for me. tested it on device.

Comment: you can check the snap shot it works on my device both the image and text scroll from right to left. if it's is not working you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: /// slash ...not worked..How remove 1 slash in three slash   file:///mnt/sdcard/osVodigi/Images/shop.png

Comment: OUTPUT Is:  <html><head></head><body><center><img src="file://mnt/sdcard/osVodigi/Images/shop.png"></center></body></html>

Comment: don't use hardcoded path. if you do exactly as above it should work. Like String imagePath = "file://"+ f.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename; and then in your html use the imagePath as above.