# Open image with webview

Tags: android, python, image, android-webview

How can I show an image file using WebView? It just shows the bytes of the image. I looked on the documentation page and I could not find an answer.

```
import android

droid = android.Android()
droid.webViewShow('file:///sdcard/Download/grand_canyon.jpg', None)
```

Comment: show what you have tried, simply asking for code here may result in down votes

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview