# Display local image in Android WebView on Marshmallow (ERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: android, html, image, webview

I'd like to be able to display images in local directories such as /sdcard/Pictures/ and /sdcard/Download/ in a WebView.

Here is what I've tried:

I have an image file called "levels.png" that I copied from my computer to my device. It is at the "root" of the internal storage that I can access through my computer. This is the /sdcard/ path.

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String imagePath = "file://" + base + "/levels.png";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

The above code just shows a broken image icon.

```
loadUrl("file:///"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/levels.png");
```

This code shows me the "Webpage not available" page with the upside down android. It says:

> The webpage at **file:///storage/emulated/0/levels.png** could not be loaded because:
>   net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

If I change the file name to a file I know does not exist, I get **ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** instead. So it seems that the app finds the file but can't access it due to a permissions problem. In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also call all of these methods in my WebView before loadUrl:

```
getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
```

I've only been able to find solutions that load images from the app's assets folder but that is **not** what I'm trying to do. I'd like to simply be able to specify the exact path of an image on the device and display it in a WebView. (I promise what I'm trying to do makes sense for my application).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - local image in webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview)

Comment: My issue was a permissions issue. See my answer below to see that the solution is different from the possible duplicate. I needed to be able to access images stored anywhere on the device's storage and display them in a WebView. Despite having the correct permissions in the manifest, I was still getting an error saying access was denied. I discovered that this was because of Marshmallow's new permissions system. I edited the title to add some clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. That was way more difficult that it should have been.

So here was the problem:
I was using an Android Marshmallow device as my test device. It seems that the `<uses-permission ../>` tag for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not work on Marshmallow. You are required to use the new permissions API to request permissions at runtime.

Check out the correct answer to this question for code:
[READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android)