# Why is the image not showing in android app in webview?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, webview

The html code is as follows for the image :

```
<img src="file:///res/drawable/jobs.jpg" style="margin-left:1em; height:300px; width:300px; border-radius:50%;">
```

The image is located in the "drawable folder" and this html document is in the "assets" folder. The directory structure is such :
App->src->main->assets; 
and App->src->main->res->drawable

[Android - local image in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127696/android-local-image-in-webview)
In this link, they say that put the image file in assets folder then it would load, but if i do that, an error pops up saying that this folder can only hold .xml files.

I also tried ../drawable/jobs.jpg but that didnt work too

Even tried ../../drawable/jobs.jpg, no luck there too.

Can someone help me out here really stuck!

Comment: is this OS specific ?

Comment: Yes, Android @AbdulWahab

Comment: sorry for that delay, I guess that is probably Nougat specific,
if that is the case, I will try to fix the issue, if you still need the solution.

Comment: Yes, I need the solution still, and really need it as soon as possible thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```html
<img src="file:///android_asset/jobs.jpg" style="margin-left:1em; height:300px; width:300px; border-radius:50%;">
```

Put your image file in app->src->main->assets

Have your html page in the assets folder as well.

Comment: Error : the file should be .xml

Comment: Is your image located in assets folder?

Comment: No (bcoz it says that only .xml files are allowed in assets folder ), therefore the images are stored in the drawable folder

Comment: Can u post the exact error message?  Also Try with .png image file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code

```
web_object.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", "<img src='test.jpg' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have 5 other images that i need to load in the same html file, so if there's a way to do that then this can be a viable option